# Getting started with microchips

Tags: microchip

I am curious about small processor (whats the correct term?) chips that I can interact with my cell phone.  But my current internet searches have made me realize how ignorant in this technology I am.  Can anyone suggest a good starting point for learning & working on these?  Here is what I am thinking of:

1. wifi and/or bluetooth enabled
2. Write and secure code to put onto the chip ( bluetooth?)
3. general and affordable chip technology I can buy to start coding on and learning more about this.
4. what languages and OS are supported

I know this is very vague, but this is such a new domain to me, I am not sure where to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do worse than purchase a Raspberry PI. It has Bluetooth (get a PI 3), It's also designed to be cheap enough to mess about with without worrying too much if it breaks.

Comment: I was really looking for something smaller (and portable) but I will checkout Raspberry PI as a way to get better understanding of microprocessor programming.